# Access - Query to find changing values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that contains all the weekly info for each employee by week. I want to create a query that shows me each employee's rates over the year, but I don't want to see duplicates.

For instance, Mary has RateX in Week1, RateY in Week2 through Week15, RateZ in Week 16. I want a query that spits out:

Name  Week  Rate
Mary   1    RateX
Mary   2    RateY
Mary   16   RateZ

And so forth for each employee. How can I do this? I've tried doing a criteria where the rate can't be the same as the rate for [Week]-1, but that seems to exclude the first week. Maybe some kind of Group By? I welcome any help.

Thanks,
Joel

Comment: Nevermind. It was as simple as Group By Employee and Rate, and First on the Week. I figured it out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP really should delete it...

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple as Group By Employee and Rate, and First on the Week.